# How to navigate to a working directory in ProcessBuilder

Tags: clearcase, processbuilder, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am trying use Process builder and execute a cleartool command from a drive setup for clearcase. Below is my code and it seems to return null. Can any one please suggest how to fix this issue.

```
String[] cmdList = {"cmd.exe","/C","M:", "cd Test_SrcCd_Dev_Dyn","cleartool lsactivity -l TestActivity@My_PVOB"};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
```

My clearcase repository is configured in M: drive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify the sequence of command to make sure you are in the right directory.

But first:

```
cleartool lsactivity -l TestActivity@My_PVOB
```

This should work from any directory (except you need to be in the view to resolve the extended pathnames of the file)

Can you first confirm that this works?

```
String[] cmdList = {"cmd.exe","/C", "cleartool lsactivity -l TestActivity@My_PVOB"};
```

You can also replace in your original command your cleartool lsact by a:

```
cleartool pwv
```

To check you are in the right directory/view.

Try also to display the path, to check that 'cleartool.exe' is in it.

Comment: Hi @VonC, When you say (except you need to be in the view to resolve the extended pathnames of the file). Does that mean that I need to do the below part in cmd.exe ? cd M: cd Test_SrcCd_Dev_Dyn and then execute cleartool lsactivity -l TestActivity@My_PVOB ? Right now if I execute cleartool lsactivity -l TestActivity@My_PVOB from C:\ then I get "Unable to determine VOB for pathname My_PVOB".

Please suggest.

Comment: @user2732988 yes: `m:`, then `cd m:\yourView`, then `cleartool lsact`. But don't remember to simplify first: replace the `cleartool lsact` by a `cleartool pwv` to see if you are in the right view.